# How to access members of associative array from AJAX Response

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a shorthand ajax call that triggers on a selection box change.

```
<script type'text/javascript'>
    $('#selection_project').change(function(event) {
        $.post('info.php', { selected: $('#selection_project option:selected').val()},
            function(data) {
                $('#CTN').html(data);
           }
       );            
   }); 
</script>
```

It works, but the response from the server is this:

```
if (isset($_POST['selected']))
    $selected = $_POST['selected'];
    $results['selected'] = $selected;
    $response = json_encode($results);

    echo $response;
```

$results is an associative array with many values from a SQL query.

My question is how do I access any particular element?
I've tried things like

```
data.selected
```

or,

```
data['selected']
```

I also understand that somewhere in the .post method there should be a statement defining the alternative dataType, such as

```
'json',
```

or a

```
datatype: 'json',
```

but after lots of searching, not a single example I could find could provide the actual syntax of using alternative dataTypes in the .post method. 
I would have just used the .ajax method but after pulling my hair out I cannot figure out why that one isn't working, and .post was, so I just stuck with it.
If someone could give me a little push in the right direction I would appreciate it so much!!

EDIT: Here is my .ajax attempt, can't figure out why it's not working. Maybe i've been staring at it too long.

```
<script type'text/javascript'>

    $('#selection_project').change(function(event) {
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'pvnresult.php',
            data: { selected: $('#selection_project option:selected').val()},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $('#CTN').html(data);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to log what exactly returned from info.php. Possible there are no data at all&

```
$('#selection_project').change(function(event) {
    $.post('info.php', {
        selected: $('#selection_project option:selected').val()},
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#CTN').html(data);
       }
   );            
});
```

--- Update. Sorry, I can't leave comments

You shold parse your json with JSON.parse before use:

```
$('#selection_project').change(function(event) {
    $.post('info.php', {
        selected: $('#selection_project option:selected').val()},
        success: function(data){
            var result = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#CTN').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the whole array with all the data shows up in the #CTN element.

Comment: @LoganVoss by array, do you mean object? an associative array in php json encoded would become an object in js. at least, in the form you've presented in the question.

Comment: @KevinB yes, what shows up is basically {"0":{"Project_ID":"1","Global_Project_Number":"99999", etc. until where I appended 'selected' to the end.

Comment: yeah, that's an object, with a `"0"` key. `foo["0"].Project_ID`

Comment: I got it! thanks also to @kevinB, a combination of this answer and your help fixed it! I did JSON.PARSE and figured it out. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

> Point to note: In your Javascript, you were doing:

`dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $('#CTN').html(data);
            }`

> This implies, you expect `JSON` Data - not just plain `HTML`. 
> Now in your  to get your `JSON` Data as an Object in `Javascript` you could do:

```
        success: function(data){
            if(data){
               // GET THAT selected KEY 
               // HOWEVER, BE AWARE THAT data.selected  
               // MAY CONTAIN OTHER DATA-STRUCTURES LIKE ARRAYS AND/OR OBJECTS
               // IN THAT CASE, TO GET THE EXACT DATA, YOU MAY JUST DO SOMETHING LIKE:
               // IF OBJECT: 
               // $('#CTN').html(data.selected.THE_KEY_YOU_WANT_HERE);
               // OR IF ARRAY:
               // $('#CTN').html(data.selected['THE_KEY_YOU_WANT_HERE']);   
               $('#CTN').html(data.selected);                 
            }
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean? I thought .html is similiar to changing the innerhtml of the element

Comment: @LoganVoss   Yes, you use `.html()` to change the innerHTML of any DOM  Object in JQuery but that is only if you are expecting an `HTML` String or Plain String. Your Code explicitly demands & expects `JSON`, which is not the same as Plain String/HTML and thus would not behave as you anticipated.